Visual Studio 2022 - XAML Designer not opening for WinUI project
It’s impossible to open any .xaml file in XAML designer - any time I try to open a XAML file with XAML Designer it's opening with text editor instead
What I tried:

make sure Tools > Options > XAML Designer is enabled
make sure Tools > Options > Environemnt > Preview Features > Use previews of the .NET SDK is enabled
disable XAML Designer, re-launch, enable XAML Designer, re-launch
select .xaml file in Solution Explorer and press F7, or Shift-F7
select .xaml file in Solution Explorer, right click, Open With…, choose XAML Designer or XAML Designer with Encoding
make sure Visual Studio is updated to latest version
uninstall Visual Studio, remove the contents of AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio, VisualStudio Services, VSCommon and VSApplicationInsights folders, restart, reinstall Visual Studio

Visual Studio Community 2022, v. 17.12.1
Target OS: Windows
Target OS version: 10.0.19041.0
Target Framework: .NET 8.0
Any ideas on how do I make XAML Designer to wor

At the moment no, there's no designer.
But there's an ongoing plan for Visual Studio designer and we might see some progress in the upcoming WinAppSdk v1.7.
If you want a designer right now, you should checkout HotDesign from Uno Platform which is based on WinUI for Windows.
